# How to add overlay to an UIImageView with tint and some text in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I created a `UIStackView` which contains `UIImageView`s to launch the gallery. However, this `UIStackView` will only show 3 items, and the third item will have an overlay with the number of images in the gallery. Similar to the image bellow:

[image]

The question is; how do I add the black tint and "+3" text on the `UIImageView` in Swift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create UIView   "dynamicView" it like a mainView
2. Create A UIImageView add to "dyanamicView"
3. Create a another View for transparentColor shadow.named as "tranpView"
4. Create Label and center the position. Label is added to "tranpView"
5. And Last add the "dynamicView" view to self.view

   ```
      let dynamicView=UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 200, 200, 200))
       dynamicView.backgroundColor=UIColor.clearColor()

       let imageView=UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200))
       imageView.image = UIImage(named: "bg.png")
       dynamicView.addSubview(imageView)

       let tranpView=UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200))
       tranpView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
       tranpView.backgroundColor = tranpView.backgroundColor!.colorWithAlphaComponent(0.3)

       let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
       label.text = "+3"
       label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20)
       label.center = tranpView.center;
       tranpView.addSubview(label)

        dynamicView.addSubview(tranpView)

       self.view.addSubview(dynamicView)
     //Just add to stackView directly replace the "self.view"
   ```

   [image: Output]

Comment: looks like I've a problem with this. Would you please have a look at, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44632424/check-landscape-portrait-orientation-in-an-imessage-app-extension ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `UIView` that has 3 subviews:

1. The `UIImage` gallery which is `UIImageView`
2. `UIView` with black backgroundcolor and alpha 0.3
3. `UILabel` with the +3 text.

Comment: Which one will be the subview of other though? I tried adding subviews to an UIImageView but did not work for me.

Comment: As I mentioned, Use a super view that will have 3 subviews (image view, tinted view, and the label)

Comment: When I do that, it caused problems with UIStackView, are there any other alternative solutions?